# update mysql data using bootstrap popup modal

Tags: php, mysql, modal-dialog, popup, crud

I am an autodidact in php and I have seen some code on bootstrap popup modal. I want to use to have some ease at office in monitoring staff data locally. The application can be reached through this link: [leads to the web interface where i was stuck](http://atcos.itl4nd.com) with credentials:
Email : **atcos@atcos.itl4nd.com**
Password : **opsup**
My problem is when I click detail button, modal popups correctly but when I click edit or delete  button, the screen gets dark and data is not displayed. I can see data when i inspect the page.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd highly recommend reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some pointers on what a question should include. Additionally, I recommend this topic: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

Your modal trigger buttons are missing the important `data-target` attribute.
In your application, you should change:

```html
<a href="#del91408" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal">Delete</a>
```

to:

```html
<button type="button" data-target="#detail91408" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal">Delete</button>
```

for all 3 buttons.

Also don't put one modal inside of another modal, put them next to one another:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your promptitude in helping me. I am still facing the same bug after implementing your code. I also appreciate the advice on how to ask question and the reminder against providing a link to external website. I wanna show you some portion of code of where i get stuck. How shall I proceed?

Comment: @lay layon, that's strange because I live-tested it in chrome devtools inspector and it worked as expected

Comment: I tried implementing your guidance still stuck, I also tried to copy paste my code, stackoverflow system is not allowing me to post the code wherein problem arose.

Comment: I tried implementing your guidance but still stuck, I also tried to copy paste my code, stackoverflow system is not allowing me to post the code wherein problem arose. Is there away or conditions I may observe to send you the code directly. In other words, is there a possibility to pay for a service. Thanks.